# Parse unique records CSV

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, csv, hash

I have a CSV which contains:

```
"ScanDateTime",       "ScanDate",   "PrintIDName",     "Section","Page","ZoneNumber","Cyan","Magenta","Yellow","Black"
"2013-12-11 12:19:57","2013/12/11","Press 40: Wed- First Good","D","1","1","0.543378","0.52948","0.552927","0.558979"
"2013-12-11 12:19:57","2013/12/11","Press 40: Wed- First Good","D","1","2","0.53521","0.517317","0.543839","0.549084"
"2013-12-11 12:19:57","2013/12/11","Press 40: Wed- First Good","D","1","3","0.527715","0.509898","0.526554","0.540249"
"2013-12-11 12:19:57","2013/12/11","Press 41: Wed- First Good","D","1","4","0.540551","0.517619","0.535687","0.551253"
"2013-12-12 12:19:57","2013/12/13","Press 40: Wed- First Good","D","1","5","0.552748","0.527429","0.546477","0.563483"
"2013-12-12 12:19:57","2013/12/13","Press 40: Wed- First Good","D","1","6","0.547891","0.526122","0.534965","0.559098"
"2013-12-12 12:19:57","2013/12/13","Press 40: Wed- First Good","D","1","7","0.544341","0.53547","0.552707","0.563052"
"2013-12-12 12:19:57","2013/12/13","Press 41: Wed- First Good","D","1","8","0.535602","0.523324","0.546354","0.552857"
"2013-12-12 12:23:36","2013/12/13","Press 41: Wed- First Good","D","10","1","0.534327","0.522695","0.546672","0.550833"
```

see after 1 to 8 zone_number it repeats iteration from zone 1 to 8. and after 8 zone the page number changes.

**Here is what I want:**

I want to pick uniques dates from ScanDateTime and their corresponding ScanDates, and ScanDates' corresponding PrintIDName, and PrintIDNames' corresponding Section, Pages, ZoneNumber and their Color values.

I may be in hash structure or array of hashes or whatever but want to parse it then.

I am googling and stacking it for two days but no success.

What I have tried so far is to copy all rows in array and then tried to read from the array but again no success.

**Update:**

This is like one to many relation. 1 ScanDateTime has_many ScanDate.

1 `ScanDate` `has_many` `PrintIDName`.

1 `PrintIDName` `has_many` `Sections, Pages`.

1 `Section+Page` `has_many` `ZoneNumbers` and `has_many colors through ZoneNumber`

and what I want is in the attached structure.

[image: What i Want is]

Note: In image I have mention only one flow for the clearness

What have i tried is:

```
CSV_CONFIG = {headers: true, header_converters: :symbol, converters: :numeric}

CSV.foreach(CSV_FILE, CSV_CONFIG) do |row|
    page_densities << ::DensityFeed.new(row: row).row_densities
end

class DensityFeed < Struct.new(:scandatetime, :scan_date, :printidname, :section, :page, :zone_number, :cyan, :magenta, :yellow, :black, :page_master_id, :page_number, :issue_date)
  COLOR_IDS = {cyan: 1, magenta: 2, yellow: 3, black: 4}

  def initialize(attr)
    @row = attr[:row]
  end

  def row_densities()
    psm_id = page_master_id
    ph_id = page_header_id
    pn = page_number
    col_indx = @row[:zonenumber]
    COLOR_IDS.keys.map do |color|
      PageDensity.create(row_index: COLOR_IDS[color], column_index: col_indx, color_id: COLOR_IDS[color], density: @row[color], page_score_master_id: psm_id, page_number: pn, page_header_id: ph_id)
    end
  end    
end
```

Comment: It's not clear to me what you mean exactly.  Do you have an example of the output you'd like?  Also, attach the code you've tried and explain what doesn't work about it. "No success" doesn't tell us what went wrong or how to help you.

Comment: Ok, that makes more sense.  Are you sure you attached the right code though?  It doesn't look related to the CSV file contents at all.

Comment: @NickVeys oh sorry just updated code. I have just this code. updated

Comment: Nice question it is..

Comment: Still very slim on an actual question. You should provide the code (at least the constructor) of `DensityFeed` and some more info on what you would expect and how it does not work. The more concrete your question is the better your answers will be. The code you provided will just create `DensityFeed` objects from `row` arrays (which are arrays of objects), but there is no tree building involved so far.

Comment: @NickVeys is it enough now ?

Comment: @G.B: Hmmh, I had to read up on that. But without knowing your `CSV_CONFIG` we cannot even tell what *Kind* of objects you are passing around. As far as I can tell your `DensityFeed` object only serves as some kind of factory for the actual `PageDensity` objects you actually seem interested in. I can assume it is some kind of `ActiveRecord` derivative, but I am still at a complete loss how your ids and your `page_number`s are generated. *And* there is still no sign of any tree building (which would probably be premature at the current stage of knowledge).

Comment: @NickVeys updated again

Comment: @G.B: Now it is at least possible to understand what you are doing, however I still feel at a loss on *why* you are doing this. A single row of input from the CSV-file gets multiplied into an array of 4 `PageDensity` objects, one for each of `:cyan`, `:magenta`, `:yellow` and `:black` in whatever random order `Hash` will provide them. These will be appended to a `page_densities` array which which you do … nothing. I can only assume this works so far as you are not telling us otherwise, but how do you want to build your tree?

Comment: yes just the tree in hashes or array or whatever but should be parseable easily

Comment: @G.B: I take your 'yes' to mean my previous description of what you have achieved is correct. From your description I cannot tell what objects you want to organize in the tree, but your `page_densities` object will now be an array consisting of entries of arrays with 4 `PageDensity` objects each. I do not consider this a particularly useful structure for whatever tree you intend to build, but you can of course turn it into one. Btw: StackOverflow suggests moving this discussion to a chat, we should probably comply.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55821/discussion-between-g-b-and-patru).